# Transition shared element breaks when for Activity called onStop()

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-lifecycle, shared-element-transition

I open from ActivityA ActivityB with shared element transition. It's work properly. When I press "Back" button, shared element similarly work properly and I see close animation.

But if I press the "Home" button and after that I return to the application (ActivityB), and after that I click "Back" to go to ActivityA, the transition does not work.

Same situation with three activity.

ActivityA **-(work)->** ActivityB **-(work)->** ActivityC

after that I start to press the "Back" button

ActivityC **-(work)->** ActivityB **-(DONT WORK)->** ActivityA

work - it's mean shared element transition work and i see animation

For start Activity I use

```java
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat
                        .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), itemView, transitionName);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Try change Manifest (DONT WORK)

```
android:name=".ActivityB"
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:parentActivityName=".ActivityA"
```

Try save shared elements (DONT WORK)

```java
setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapSharedElements(List<String> names, Map<String, View> sharedElements) {
                if (names.size() > 0)
                    mSharedElementsNames.addAll(names);
                else
                    names.addAll(mSharedElementsNames);

                if (sharedElements.size() > 0)
                    mSharedElementsMap.putAll(sharedElements);
                else
                    sharedElements.putAll(mSharedElementsMap);
            }
        });
```

I noticed that after minimizing the application, the onMapSharedElements() is not called when press "Back". Otherwise the call is happening.

I guess onStop() call break the shared element transition. But i can't avoid this. Any help or ideas, please

Comment: I can't believe there is no other posts about this. No one noticed this before?

Comment: I have run into this error too. Have u found any solutions for it?

Comment: reported issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158553240

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62381012/3529488) answer.

Simply, just add below snippet code to `onStop` of ActivityB

```
override fun onStop() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && !isFinishing) {
        Instrumentation().callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(this, Bundle())
    }
    super.onStop()
}
```