# Android clears Activity to Activity shared element transition exit animation after pressing power button

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition, shared-element-transition

I'm working on implementing a basic `Activity` transition animation with a shared element from a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` to a full screen details `Activity` screen. The animation works well under regular circumstances. So when clicking on an image in the grid it scales to the full screen image and on exiting the reverse happens. But if you press the power button and return to the app while the details screen is visible, Android seems to clear all registered shared element/transitions so the full screen image instead of scaling back into the grid it just fades out. I tried registering `SharedElementCallbacks` in both `Activities` which are called properly without the power button press but neither gets called after pressing the power button. I'd appreciate any suggestions to help solve this problem.

These are the places that I've added code to support the shared element transition:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.imageview) ImageView imageView;

    private Item item;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        itemView.setTag(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBind(int position) {
        super.onBind(position);
        this.item = list.get(position);

        imageView.setTransitionName(item.getId());
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext().getApplicationContext())
                .load(item.getUrl())
                .centerCrop()
                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK)))
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(imageView);
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    public void setUp() {
        ...

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(view -> {
            MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder)view.getTag();
            View view = viewHolder.imageView;

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Item.TAG, viewHolder.getItem());

            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                    this,
                    view,
                    view.getTransitionName());

            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

        });

        ...
    }
}


public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.imageview) ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        supportPostponeEnterTransition();

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Item item = (Item) bundle.getSerializable(Item.TAG);
        imageView.setTransitionName(item.getId());

        final RequestListener<Drawable> requestListener = new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                supportStartPostponedEnterTransition();
                return false;
            }
        };

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(item.getUrl())
                .centerCrop()
                .addListener(requestListener)
                .into(imageView);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I believe this is a bug starting from API 29 in

1. Activity-2-Activity
2. Activity-Fragment
3. Fragment-Activity

shared element transitions. It works fine in API < 29 and Fragment-Fragment transitions.

While transitioning from **`ActivityA`** to **`ActivityB`** and returning back from **`ActivityB`** to **`ActivityA`** everything works normally unless you are on **ActivityB** and send your app on background or lock device screen, then you come to the app where **ActivityB** is opened, now pressing back button or returning to **ActivityA** loses all shared element reverse transitions even if you have override the `sharedElementReturnTransition`

> I found a simple hack to fix this issue which is making our
> transitions to not work normally -

While sending the `ActivityB` to background it calls the **`onPause() > onStop()`** lifecycle methods of the activity and now inside your
**`onStop()`** you can check for the following conditions,
if the activity is not finished and your API > 29, then pass the current Bundle in `callActivityOnSaveInstanceState()`,

> Kotlin Code
> // override this method in your ActivityB

```
override fun onStop() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && !isFinishing) {
            Instrumentation().callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(this, Bundle())
        }
        super.onStop()
    }
```

> Java Code
> // override this lifecycle method in your ActivityB

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && !isFinishing()){
            new Instrumentation().callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(this, new Bundle());
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Nice hack! Worked for me.

Comment: Could you please share the code in java? The Original question uses java, so i think it would be better if a solution in the same language is provided

Comment: @AshutoshPatoa Sure, please have a look above, I have updated the code for java too.

Comment: is there any risk to calling `callActivityOnSaveInstanceState()' on versions less than 29?  in other words, remove the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.Q'

Comment: No risks by not validating this, as this issue arises only in the **Android Q**, so does not make sense to call this in **< Q** that's the only reason. I'm not sure about Android 11 as I haven't tested out there yet.